# Missing control sequence inserted. \end{tabulary} error in revtex4-2 template aps

Tags: latex, tabular

I am writing a paper in APS journal template : revtex4-2, when I import my table I have this error :
Missing control sequence inserted. \end{tabulary}. But this table has no problem in other template for example IEEE. I dont know how fix it. I really appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,floatfix,footinbib,notitlepage,superscriptaddress,groupaddress,showpacs]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics,times,bm,bbm,bbold,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,dsfont,hyperref,mathrsfs,color,caption,subcaption,cancel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    
    \preprint{AIP/123-QED}
    
    %\title[Sample title]{Sample Title:\\with Forced Linebreak\footnote{Error!}}% Force line breaks with \\
    \title[]
    
    \author{}
    \affiliation{}
    
    \author{}
    \affiliation{}
    \email{}

    
    \date{\today}
    \begin{abstract}
        
    \end{abstract}
    
%   \keywords{}
%   \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}

    \section{Theoretical Analysis}
    
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{List of Parameters Values }
        \label{table:1}
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=8.5 cm}
            \begin{tabulary}{\columnwidth}{@{}llr@{}}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Parameters} & \textbf{Values} & \textbf{Units}\\
                \midrule
                $\lambda$   &  1550            & $nm$ \\        
                \bottomrule     
            \end{tabulary}
        \end{adjustbox} 
    \end{table}.

\end{document}
%
% ****** End of file aipsamp.tex ******
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the new and much more flexible `tabularray` package instead.

Also don't scale content which contains text, this will result in an suboptimal result. If in your real document, you must make the table smaller, use a smaller font size instead of scaling it with `adjustbox`.

(you should really clean up your preamble and remove duplicates and outdated packages)

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,floatfix,footinbib,notitlepage,superscriptaddress,groupaddress,showpacs]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics,times,bm,bbm,bbold,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,dsfont,hyperref,mathrsfs,color,caption,subcaption,cancel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}


\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \preprint{AIP/123-QED}
    
    %\title[Sample title]{Sample Title:\\with Forced Linebreak\footnote{Error!}}% Force line breaks with \\
    \title[]
    
    \author{}
    \affiliation{}
    
    \author{}
    \affiliation{}
    \email{}

    
    \date{\today}
    \begin{abstract}
        
    \end{abstract}
    
%   \keywords{}
%   \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}

    \section{Theoretical Analysis}
    
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{List of Parameters Values }
        \label{table:1}
%        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=8.5 cm}
            \begin{tblr}{width=0.8\linewidth,colspec={@{}X[l]X[l]X[r]@{}}}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Parameters} & \textbf{Values} & \textbf{Units}\\
                \midrule
                $\lambda$   &  1550            & $nm$ \\        
                \bottomrule     
            \end{tblr}
%        \end{adjustbox} 
    \end{table}

\end{document}
%
% ****** End of file aipsamp.tex ******
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your perfect suggestion! It s very helpful.  (It saves my time )